# How to test packet loss?

Tags: networking, dpdk

I'm working on ovs-dpdk, I want to test whether a port has packet loss. For hardware switch, you could use IXIA or some to send continuous packet, but this is virtual switch and I have no IXIA.

So I use ping to test this, but ping's packet rate is too low, could I use pktgen to test this? If I use pktgen, how to verify if there is packet loss?

Or is there some other method? Thank you~

Comment: There are many ways to do this. You can do a packet capture with tcpdump or similar. You can use iperf or other traffic generating tools to generate a lot of packets. Then you analyse the pcap(s). To verify packet loss you need to count packets sent vs packets received, if you can not access counters inside the network middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a literate of small 64-byte packets using DPDK applications, like [DPDK Pktgen](http://pktgen-dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [Cisco TRex](https://trex-tgn.cisco.com) or even the testpmd app included in DPDK. All those software generators will be able to generate quite a lot of traffic in virtualized environment as well as on the host.

If all that you are interested in is a packet loss, you can use any of the listed above options. TRex and Pktgen do support RFC 2544 tests as well.

A typical setup would include one VM with a generator, another VM with either a generator or a forwarding DPDK application (like l2fwd or l3fwd).

The packet loss is basically the difference between sent and received packets, so just run the test for a while and then see the difference.

Overall, it might be a bit scary at the beginning, but once you understand the basics, it is quite easy to setup and use. And you can always ask a question on StackOverflow...